# Copy sheets from all (closed) workbooks within a folder on my desktop and paste them in current workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the a sheet named "Zeit&Kostenerfassung" from all workbook in a file on my desktop. The code should open them (one after the other) and copy the wanted worksheet; paste it in the current workbook and also the sheets should be renamed (Zeit&Kostenerfassung1 ; Zeit&Kostenerfassung2; ...) because they obviously can't can't all have the same name.

After pasting the workbooks in the file on my desktop should be closed again.

I have tried the below code that unfortunately doesn't work.

Any help on that would be very much appreciated!

```
Sub CopySheetFromFileOnDesktop()

Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim wksDest As Worksheet
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
Set wksDest = wkbDest.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

MyPath = "C:\Users\..."

If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsx")

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFile)
Set wksSource = wkbSource.Worksheets("Zeit&Kostenerfassung")
Sheets("Zeit&Kostenerfassung").Copy 
Before:=Workbooks("PullDataFromOutlook").Sheets(SheetIndex)
wkbSource.Close savechanges:=False
MyFile = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Completed...", vbInformation


End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets("Zeit&Kostenerfassung").Copy` should be `wksSource.Copy`. • *"doesn't work."* is no good error description. Instead tell us which errors you get and where. Or what your code does vs. what you expect it to do.

Comment: ...and `SheetIndex` is not initialized.

Comment: To avoid errors like a not declared `SheetIndex` variable, I highly recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful